# Kubernetes: port-forwarding automatically for services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, kubernetes

I have a rails project that using postgres database. I want to build a database server using Kubernetes and rails server will connect to this database.

For example here is my defined `postgres.yml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
  - name: "5432"
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: hades_dev
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: "1234"
        name: postgres
        image: postgres:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        resources: {}
        stdin: true
        tty: true
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/
          name: database-hades-volume
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: database-hades-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: database-hades-volume
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: database-hades-volume
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
```

I run this by following commands: `kubectl run -f postgres.yml`.

But when I try to run rails server. I always meet following exception:

```
PG::Error
invalid encoding name: utf8
```

I try to forwarding port, and rails server successfully connects to database server:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
postgres-3681891707-8ch4l   1/1       Running   0          1m
```

Then run following command:

```
kubectl port-forward postgres-3681891707-8ch4l 5432:5432
```

I think this solution not good. How can I define in my `postgres.yml` so I don't need to port-forwarding manually as above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try by exposing your service on NodePort and then accessing the service on that port.

Check here  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport

Comment: I have convert my service to NodePort but problem still same.

Comment: Try this : 

kubectl expose service postgres --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer and then run kubectl get services and see the port number on which that service is exposed

Comment: You means conver type to LoadBalancer? I have tried, and see that the publish port is 32395. And then I try again NodePort with nodePort=32395. But the problem still same. thanks.

Comment: This is working for me : 
Remove the service part from this file, keep only the deployment one and then call this command kubectl expose deployment postgres --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer . After this, if you run kubectl get services you will see postgres service with port info something like 80/SOME_PORT_NUMBER. Try to access the service with your http://VM ip:PORT_NUMBER

Comment: I want SOME_PORT_NUMBER is constant. can I do that.

Comment: I tried fixing it by using nodePort but then it is  not accessible from outside.
you can make a api which after the service is exposed query the kubernetes services API and get the port information from it. That will return all the services and then you can query based upon your service name and get it port information, which later on you can use in your code to do other stuff